# In Scala Functional Programming, is there an idiomatic way to map with a state?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

A conventional mapping function has the signature `A => B`, to transform a `F[A]` into an `F[B]`, for example a `List[A]` into a `List[B]`.

But what if do you do if the mapping function should carry some state along which is required for the computation of `B`?

Say, the mapping function looks like this: `(A, S) => (B, S)`, where S is the type of the `State`. For each `A`, the previously returned `S` is passed into the mapping function, while initially a `zero` element is provided for the state. The mapping function then returns a new state (along with the result) which is then again passed along with the next value, and so forth.

Of course, `.map` is not powerful enough to do this, so the solution must be based on another operator.

For illustrative purposes, to give a concrete example, say I have a sequence of `Ints`, and I want calculate the difference of each `Int` to the previous `Int` in that sequence. The implementation of the mapping function as described above would look like this:

```scala
  def mapping(currentElement: Int, previousElement: Option[Int]): (Option[Int], Option[Int]) = {
    (previousElement.map(currentElement - _), Some(currentElement))
  }
```

The initial `zero` value for  `previousElement` would be `None`, and after the first element it would always be `Some(currentElement)`. The result for each iteration would be a `Some` of the current value minus the last value, except for the first element, where it is `None`.

How could I transform, for example `List(1, 4, 3)` to `List(None, Some(3), Some(-1))` Using the `mapping` function?

(Please note that the Int-subtraction example is purely for illustrative purposes, and the question's focus is a universal solution for the described type of operation.)

Comment: Maybe `scanLeft` is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Scala 2.13.x `unfold()` method maintains a State that is carried forward similar to your example.

```
List.unfold((Option.empty[Int], List(1, 4, 3))){
  case (prev, hd::tl) => Some((prev.map(hd.-), (Some(hd),tl)))
  case (prev, Nil)    => None
}
//res0: List[Option[Int]] = List(None, Some(3), Some(-1))
```

This is available on `LazyList` and `Iterator` so it can used to create a pseudo-infinite stream.

Answer (score 3):

There are some libraries available to do "mtl-style" state passing which is what you are describing. (Check the type signatures after this snippet)

```scala
import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._

// Given an element and state, calculate next state and return value
def modifyEntry(currentElement: Int): State[Option[Int], Option[Int]] = for {
  previousElement <- State.get
  _ <- State.set[Option[Int]](Some(currentElement)) // Next State
} yield previousElement map (currentElement - _) // Calculated Value

// It is useful for hiding state and passing it implicitly
val result =
  for {
    val1 <- modifyEntry(1)
    val2 <- modifyEntry(2)
    val3 <- modifyEntry(3)
  // Final state is implicittly stored in the yielded State[Option[Int], Seq[Option[Int]]]
  } yield Seq(val1, val2, val3) 

// Run with None initial State and coerce evaluation (cats is lazy by default)
println("for-comprehension result (final state and value): " -> result.run(None).value)

// More importantly, it is _easy_ to compose with Traversables or other generic cats traits
println("traverse result (only value): " ->
  List(1,2,3).traverse(modifyEntry).runA(None).value) // List(None, Some(1), Some(1))
println("traverse result (only value): " ->
  List(1,4,3).traverse(modifyEntry).runA(None).value) // List(None, Some(3), Some(-1))
```

You would be particularly interested in the `StateFunctions` trait from `scalaz` or `State` from `cats`. Comparison: https://github.com/fosskers/scalaz-and-cats

Scalaz StateFunctions:

```scala
trait StateFunctions extends IndexedStateFunctions {
  // ...
  def get[S]: State[S, S] = State(s => (s, s))

  def put[S](s: S): State[S, Unit] = State(_ => (s, ()))
  // ...
}
```

Cats StateFunctions with some modifications:

```scala
abstract private[data] class StateFunctions {
  // ...
  def get[S]: State[S, S] = ??? // Some other code like State(s => (s, s))

  def set[S](s: S): State[S, Unit] = State(_ => (s, ()))
}
```

For cats, check the excellent docs with some other examples: https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/state.html

For scalaz, here is a good talk with an overview of "mtl-style" in Scala and Scalaz: [Paweł Szulc - GETTING MORE MILEAGE FROM YOUR MONADS WITH MTL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=knK70T4X7YE), though beware of the

For either of them, beware of the cons of MonadTransformers (not mtl-style/traits, see the second part): http://degoes.net/articles/effects-without-transformers

Comment: I see the similarity in type signatures and I'm looking into this, but so far the practical application is not clear to me, how to get from `List(1, 4, 3)` to `List(None, Some(3), Some(-1))` using `StateFunctions`

Comment: State would be preserved by normal map (and flatMap), so if you want to transform a list and conserve state just use that.

Comment: Hi @ig-dev, I modified the answert to illustrate your example, sorry for the delay.

Comment: Also @ig-dev, here is the example you commented producing the correct output: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/vLgGCRF/2

Answer (score 1):

The "operator" you are looking for is `fold`:

```
List(1, 4, 3).foldLeft(None: Option[Int], List[Option[Int]]())
   ((acc, curr) => (Some(curr), acc._1.map(_ - curr) :: acc._2))
    ._2
    .reverse
```

Another way to think about is using `zip`:

```
val xs = List(1, 4, 3)

val result = None :: xs.zip(xs.drop(1)).map(currAndNext => Some(currAndNext._2 - currAndNext._1))
```

Comment: This answers the example well, but it only works for finite data-structures. It would not work if F[A] is an infinite stream (which is what I need)

Comment: @ig-dev depends on what you using for the Stream. I am believe fs2 would work with this

Comment: @sinanspd Yeah? I wouldn't think so because folds do not return intermediate results. Does `fs2` have a mechanism for this?

Comment: @ig-dev I haven't looked into fs2 internals for a while so do double check but as far as I remember, fs2 fold is defined as a pull and a fold. So it pulls the new data from the Stream and then folds.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?
Note: it should be trivial to transform this to make it work for infinite stream of data using a yield.

```
  implicit class RichTraversableLike[A, Repr](coll: TraversableLike[A, Repr]) {
    def mapWithState[S, B, That](initial: S)(op: (S, A) => (S, B))(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): (S, That) = {
      var state: S = initial
      val mapped = coll.map { x: A =>
        val (newState, mappedX) = op(state, x)
        state = newState
        mappedX
      }
      state -> mapped
    }
  }
```

For your dummy example, it would look like this:

```
    List(1, 4, 3).mapWithState(Option.empty[Int]) {
      case (previousElement: Option[Int], currentElement: Int) =>
        Some(currentElement) -> previousElement.map(currentElement - _)
    }
```